# Add application to startup

Tags: vb.net, startup

How can I add my application in startup items?  I want my application to get added in startup when setup is run at Client's computer.

Also, how can it be automatically started after setup finishes?

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 2):

Create a new string value in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run in [registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry).

For example if you application name is Test and resides in c:\programfiles\test\test.exe then

create a string value called Test and save the path c:\programfiles\test\test.exe in the string value.

Let me know if you want the setup to add your application as startup application.

**Edit 1:**

Sample code :

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim regStartUp As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)

        Dim value As String

        value = regStartUp.GetValue("Myapp")

        If value <> Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() Then

            regStartUp.CreateSubKey("Myapp")
            regStartUp.SetValue("Myapp", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString())

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

You can find more details about registry [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) and details about registry class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx).

Let me know if you have any problem with the code.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still unable to do it.  Actually user chooses where the application is installed.  
Could you give me complete code how to manage it?
Thanks
Furqan

Comment: Could you kindly give me an idea how I can make Setup to add this registry key so my application runs at startup of windows? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut or a batch file that runs your program in in Start menu > Programs > Startup folder

for example in win XP this folder would be C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup or C:\Documents and Settings[YOURUSERNAME]\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: Most of the startup applications create a key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run